# Should I use get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') or get_stylesheet_directory_uri() when enqueueing my js files?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, bloginfo

I am using a Genesis theme (digital-pro), and inside of the front-page.php file (companion to functions.php) I am noticing that js files are enqueued in two different ways.

Example 1:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'localScroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.localScroll.min.js', array( 'scrollTo' ), '1.2.8b', true );
```

Example 2:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'digital-backstretch-set', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/backstretch-set.js' , array( 'jquery', 'digital-backstretch' ), '1.0.0' );
```

In the first example, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is used before concatenating the js file path, and in the second example `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` is used instead.

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be? Is it better to use one method over the other? Or in different circumstances?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from WordPress 4.7, I would use [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/), so any child theme can override the file easily: if the file exists in the child theme, `get_theme_file_uri()` returns the URI to that file, otherwise returns the file in the parent theme:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'localScroll', get_theme_file_uri( 'js/jquery.localScroll.min.js' ), array( 'scrollTo' ), '1.2.8b', true );
```

If you want to *hard* link to a file in the parent theme not allowing it to be overriden by a child theme, use [`get_parent_theme_file()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_parent_theme_file_uri/).

But responding specifically to your question, both methods do the same; in fact, `get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' )`  is a wrapper for `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` as you can see in the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/#source):

```
case 'stylesheet_directory':
    $output = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    break;
```

But I would avoid `get_bloginfo()` if a specific getter function exists; it may be more consistent in long way.

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_template_directory_uri()` still exists, are valid and can be used but those functions should be used only when you need specifically the URI of the shtylesheet/template **directory**, not a URI to a **file**.

For example, imaging we have a file located in `assets/js/script.js` whithin the theme folder; then we can use all of this options:

1. `get_styleseet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js';`
2. `get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js';`
3. `get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/js/script.js' );`

In a theme with no childs, all three options will output the **same URI**; but if you develop a child theme:

1. The option 1 will link to a file in the child theme directory whitout checking if it exists. In this case, we are required to copy the file to the child theme, even if we don't need to modify it.
2. The option 2 will link to a file in the parent theme; no options to override it (well, it can be done using some filter hooks, but not in a direct way).
3. With the option 3 you can leave the file in the parent theme if you are not going to modify it; or you can move the file to the child theme if you need to override it. No extra code is needed. As easy as it is sound.

Internally, `get_theme_file_uri()`first checks if the file exists in the stylesheet directory, if it exists it returns `get_styleseet_directory_uri() . $file;`. If the file doesn't exist in the child theme, then it returns `get_template_directory_uri() . $file;`. It is like one level up over the other functions.

Along with `get_theme_file_uri()`, `get_theme_file_path()` was introduced to get the path to the file instead of the URI; `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` and `get_parent_theme_file_path()` are also available but they will always use the parent file files, no matter if a child theme is active.

Comment: The very intuitive function name `get_theme_file_uri`.

Comment: I would avoid `get_bloginfo` as it is both a turn off name, and it is not even very correct

Comment: Totally agree @MarkKaplun

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation! I love how concatenation is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The new quatro:

```
get_theme_file_uri()
get_parent_theme_file_uri()
get_theme_file_path()
get_parent_theme_file_path()
```

came to replace the old quatro:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
get_template_directory_uri()
get_stylesheet_directory()
get_template_directory()
```

In the respective order.
The gain I would like to outline is the naming convention — much better now when you create themes.

There is one problem. 
Still, there are many WordPress installations that use WP lower than 4.7.
If you know you run WordPress 4.7 or greater you are good.